# Cypress function should('be.disabled') is not recognizing toggle element as disabled, even though it clearly is

Tags: javascript, html, cypress, ui-automation, chai

In my DOM I have an array of toggles without unique IDs. I am using `cy.get(aur-toggle)`, which I can see is returning the correct array of elements. I can also see in the cypress UI (and the console output of the step) that it is selecting the correct element after evaluating `.eq(index)`. The `yielded` field shows the correct element tag:

`<aur-toggle _ngcontent-rcs-c562="" _nghost-rcs-c138="" aria-disabled="true" aria-checked="false" id="aur-toggle--070085442" role="switch" class="disabled label-top">`

When it is checking if the element is disabled, the following error is thrown `Timed out retrying after 10000ms: expected '<aur-toggle#aur-toggle--070085442.disabled.label-top>' to be 'disabled'`. You can see even in the element selection, it has the disabled attribute.

I have also tried `('have.attr', 'disabled')` and it yielded the same results.

Any ideas, wonderful minds of stack overflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get it with

```js
('have.class', 'disabled')
```

The element does not appear to use the `disabled` attribute directly, but rather modifies it's behavior based on the class `.disabled`.